# Compression (GZip/Brotli) and encryption (Aes) problem

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, compression

Edited for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Look at these two pieces of software:

```
public static byte[] Key { get; set; } = Convert.FromBase64String("your key");
public static byte[] IV { get; set; } = Convert.FromBase64String("your IV");

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri fileFrom = new(@"whatever you want");
    Uri fileGZipCompressed = new(@"whatever you want");
    Uri fileBrotliCompressed = new(@"whatever you want");

    GZipCompressAndAesEncrypt(fileFrom, fileGZipCompressed);
    BrotliCompressAndAesEncrypt(fileFrom, fileBrotliCompressed);
}

public static void GZipCompressAndAesEncrypt(Uri input, Uri output)
{
    FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(input.LocalPath);
    FileStream outputStream = File.Create(output.LocalPath);

    GZipCompressAndAesEncrypt(inputStream, outputStream);
}

public static void GZipCompressAndAesEncrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor = AesFactory.GetAesEncryptor(Key, IV);

    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(output, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (GZipStream compressedStream = new(cryptoStream, CompressionLevel.SmallestSize))
    {
        input.CopyTo(compressedStream);
        compressedStream.Flush();
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    }
}

public static void BrotliCompressAndAesEncrypt(Uri input, Uri output)
    {
        FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(input.LocalPath);
        FileStream outputStream = File.Create(output.LocalPath);

        BrotliCompressAndAesEncrypt(inputStream, outputStream);
    }

public static void BrotliCompressAndAesEncrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor = AesFactory.GetAesEncryptor(Key, IV);

        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(output, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (BrotliStream compressedStream = new(cryptoStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
        {
            input.CopyTo(compressedStream);
            compressedStream.Flush();
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that while the first one (with GZip compression) works fine, the second one (with Brotli compression) hangs on `input.CopyTo(compressedStream)`. No errors, no exceptions. It simply stays there...

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: A very basic test I did here does not hang, so I suggest you try to narrow down where the problem is by isolating it more and more from the rest of the code. Likely you will at least get a hint as to where or what the problem might be.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I did and I'm still working on it: compression streams and encryption streams work fine if used alone... it's the combination of the two that doesn't work... Any suggestion on how to test it?

Comment: If your program consistently hangs when you run that brotli code, then try to isolate it into a test program and see if it still fails. Then try your old program that hangs and replace the input. There's too many moving parts in motion here to know exactly which one is the culprit. For instance, it may be that reading from the particular input stream hangs.